# SQL command string clean up

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, string

I have a query declared as a variable in vb.net. I would like to keep it formatted as it is for future development / better understanding, so cleanup at declaration level will not work.

```
Dim query As String = "
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT TOP 10     T.name TableName, i.Rows NumberOfRows
FROM        sys.tables T
JOIN        sys.sysindexes I ON T.OBJECT_ID = I.ID
WHERE       indid IN (0,1)
ORDER BY    i.Rows DESC, T.name ASC
) AS TableA
ORDER BY TableName ASC
"
```

I keep log in dedicated table of all SQL commands sent from app to database and this query becomes messy once passed to SQL Server as a string value in log table:

```
vbCrLf & "                SELECT * FROM (" & vbCrLf & "                SELECT TOP 10     T.name TableName, i.Rows NumberOfRows" & vbCrLf & "                FROM        sys.tables T" & vbCrLf & "                JOIN        sys.sysindexes I ON T.OBJECT_ID = I.ID" & vbCrLf & "                WHERE       indid IN (0,1)" & vbCrLf & "                ORDER BY    i.Rows DESC, T.name ASC" & vbCrLf & "                ) AS TableA" & vbCrLf & "                ORDER BY TableName ASC" & vbCrLf & "                "
```

So am looking for a way to get rid off all unnecessary characters. Is there any efficient and easy way to clean it up in order to get just clean SQL statement? No formatting such as separate lines for FROM, etc. needed.

Comment: Since you are already certain that the query works, assign it without the added lines like `Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 10 T.name TableName, i.Rows NumberOfRows FROM sys.tables T JOIN sys.sysindexes I ON T.OBJECT_ID = I.ID WHERE indid IN (0,1) ORDER BY i.Rows DESC, T.name ASC) AS TableA ORDER BY TableName ASC"`

Comment: That is definitely on option, however I would like to keep it formatted in such way for future development / better understanding. So am looking for a way to get rid off all unnecessary characters.

Comment: Since this is a log, probably only admins will be looking at it. Instead create a log viewer app that would format the text the way you want it. No need to complicate what you pass to the server.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it more clear what you're actually asking, so people don't waste any more time answering the question you've written only to find out you're actually asking something different. Be clear and concise about what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved this with regex

```
Query = Regex.Replace(Query, "\s{2,}", " ").Trim
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim query As String ="SELECT * FROM (" & vbcrlf &
        "    SELECT TOP 10 T.name TableName, i.Rows NumberOfRows" & vbcrlf &
        "    FROM  sys.tables T" & vbcrlf &
        "    JOIN sys.sysindexes I ON T.OBJECT_ID = I.ID" & vbcrlf &
        "    WHERE indid IN (0,1)" & vbcrlf &
        "    ORDER BY i.Rows DESC, T.name ASC" & vbcrlf &
        " ) AS TableA" & vbcrlf &
        " ORDER BY TableName ASC"
```